# How to dock an actionsheet

Tags: iphone, uitableview, interface-builder, uipickerview, uiactionsheet

I have an `actionsheet` which contains a `pickerView` and I have a table view behind
but when I scroll the table view the hole picker is scrolled with it.
My question is how to "dock" my `pickerview` and make it appear always at the bottom of the screen.

thanks a lot

Comment: this is kindof hard to understand.  Try this, in the IB navigator, drill down to where your Table View is.  If your Picker is on a level lower than the table view, move it up.  That way the picker isn't a child of the table view.  Otherwise, I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: thanks for your answer, actionnaly i have setted up all my components programmaticly so no IB :) , i have an rss feed reader in UITableviewController and i have a button on the navigation bar "filter" when i click on it a picker with categories shows and i can filter my news by selecting a row in the picker but i scroll my tableview with my news without dissmissing the picker this one is scrolled with the table view, he is not docked at the bottom of the screen and it's not good, so is there a programmaticly way to set the picker as not a child for tableview, thanks a lot

Comment: Thats good now better it would be to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not placing your actionSheet properly. You don't want it to be loaded 'off the screen' at all, but called and dismissed only when it's needed. A simple solution would be to pause the UI while the actionSheet is presented. I use a library on Github to handle this for me called [EAActionSheetPicker](https://github.com/EckyZero/EAActionSheetPickerDemo). It would simplify your code 'cause all you'd have to do is call:

```
NSArray *options = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", @"Four", @"Five", nil];

EAActionSheetPicker *actionPicker = [[EAActionSheetPicker alloc]initWithOptions:options];
actionPicker.textField = self.emailField;
actionPicker.delegate = self;

[actionPicker showInView:self.view];
```